# Custom table or form

Tags: customization, table

i need a form or table plugin that can be customized to do this:

For example:
I am a parcel shipping company. I need some form that can be filled out with shipping info. Later, customer logs on the site to retrive information about the parcel with associated id number.

Simple

Comment: Nothing, i looked at the table reloader and formadable...will look more today

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

- Create a public accessible form in a page. Look at the code of front end submission plugins to get an idea.
- Create a custom post type `shipping`.
- Create a custom user role `customer` with very limited capabilities (`read_shipping`, `edit_user_profile`).
- After form submission create a new `shipping` entry, register the user in your role if she hasn’t already and send an email to the person who handles shippings.
- Check all customer data, add the shipping information to the `shipping` and send an email to the customer with a link to the page holding shipping information.

There are some tricky details:

- Spam bots will hit your forms.
- Customers shouldn’t have to enter all their personal data each time new. Offer a login form, ajaxify it.
- Probably some more, you’ll see it when you start writing code. :)

I wouldn’t say *simple*.